# GMaps API v3 loading, but can't view it on page

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know the maps are loading, but for whatever reason I can't see them.

**JS**

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

**MarkUp**

```
<div id="map-canvas">

</div>
```

I know this must be simple and I'm a little confused why I can't work it out, but here is the link: http://stage.sexdiaries.co.uk/map

Comment: Your `#map-canvas` `height` is set to `100%`, but there is no parent height to reference this from.

Comment: Furthermore `<shell>` is not a valid `HTML` element.

Comment: html5 it is ;) read about it. Its awesome.

Comment: HA! I'm not even sure where to start with that reply :) Google it, its all the rage atm.

Comment: Try bing, I've heard its very good and helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the map a size:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
```

Comment: Bingo, why is it that simple... dam it!